# Tooltip in react bind with each data item in dropdown and select the data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component. There I used a menu item (dropdown list) along with tooltip. The tooltip value shows properly for each item but when I select a menu item value it is not select. My code is as below.

```
    <TextField
          select
          required
          label="Info"
          value={subTypeId}
          onChange={(event) => setsubTypeId(+event.target.value)}
          disabled={submission.loading}
          style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
        >
          {submission.investigationTypeChoices.map((option) => (
            <Tooltip title={option.focus} key={option.value}>
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.text}
              </MenuItem>
            </Tooltip>
          ))}
   </TextField>
```

I am trying when I select a value from dropdown it will select in textfield.

Comment: Could you please create a small runnable example of your code (e.g. here https://codepen.io or https://codesandbox.io)? Now it's hard to understand what's the implementation of all used components (e.g. `TextField`)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).